# How do I know the number of slots used by Bigquery query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to figure out the number of slots used by every big query query. Is there a way to find it out?

Answer (score 8):

As per google docs, this way we can calculate number of slot used(average).

Number of slot = total_slot_ms / TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_time,start_time, MILLISECOND)

```
select job_id
       ,total_slot_ms / TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_time,start_time,MILLISECOND) as num_slot
from `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
```

or manually using BQ UI execution details if you don't have access to the table above.

```
Number of slot = Slot time consumed (convert in MILLISECOND)/Elapses time (convert in MILLISECOND)
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs that you mentioned?

Comment: I can't find any reference for this calculation... wondering how you use the total_slot_ms (which is a processing time) to calculate the number of slots (which is a CPUs)?

Comment: @Soliman it's mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#calculate_average_slot_utilization

Answer (score 5):

This information is indeed available in *job.statistics.query.timeline* that forms parts of the Jobs API of BigQuery (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#resource). When you get this information it comes in an array like this:

```
timeline: 
    [ '{"elapsedMs":"750","totalSlotMs":"2795","pendingUnits":"8","completedUnits":"66","activeUnits":"9"}',
      '{"elapsedMs":"1252","totalSlotMs":"3617","pendingUnits":"1","completedUnits":"73","activeUnits":"1"}',
      '{"elapsedMs":"2944","totalSlotMs":"5643","pendingUnits":"0","completedUnits":"78","activeUnits":"0"}' ],
```

So what you can do depends on your actual question:

1) If your question is "What is the total amount of slots utilised by the query over its running time?", then look at the final value of *completedUnits*

2) If your question is "How are the slots utilised during the query's running time?", then you can build an average of `completedUnits` over the `elapsedMs` per timeslice.

Comment: If the max slots for a on-demand project is 2000, how is it that my timeline shows ` "activeUnits": "7457"` for query I recently ran? I don't think "units" == "slots".

Comment: Hi @GrahamPolley, I can offer you this thread with the BigQuery people on Twitter: https://twitter.com/eebsidian/status/1097960643498598408

Comment: I still don't understand it. I don't think anyone really does TBH. You normally shouldn't care, but if you're analysing if you need to move to flat-rate then it's important. If "activeUnits" are the number of slots the query is currently using to execute the query, and I'm using on-demand, then how can I see numbers greater than 2000 e.g. 7457?!

Comment: I suggest two things:  Take a look at how many projects you have. I'm guessing you have more than 1 and the other projects are also busy taking up slots (the quote is 2000 per project). Second thing is take a look at Stackdriver to see the breakdown of slot usage.

Comment: is it possible to do this using the "bq" cli ?

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya There are some examples on how to get this information using the command line tool here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs

Comment: You might be able to see an usage higher than 2000 because "Projects on the BigQuery on-demand pricing model are subject to per-project slot quota with transient burst capability. " which means that it might allow you to use momentaneously a higher processing capacity that the assigned because at that moment there's availability and it will just make it faster for your (the total slot usage over time would be the same) source: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots

Comment: Also take into account that [activeUnits does not correlate slot usage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#QueryTimelineSample) and that on-demand grants up to 2000 concurrent slots depending on the availability, however (totalSlotMs is the cumulative)[https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#QueryTimelineSample]

Answer (score 3):

There is a Slot Utilization Chart in [Stackdriver Monitoring For BigQuery](https://app.google.stackdriver.com/services/bigquery)
It shows Allocated and Available Slot for selected Project

Unfortunatelly, I don't think such stats is available on per each query basis

Comment: I am checking the stack driver. I could see that zero slots are allocated in specific time period. But I had a query running during that time period. So I am confused.

Comment: I am running a query from X project but using data sources of Y project. Will it utilize the slots from project X or project Y?

Comment: project X will be your project to check within

Comment: I see zero slots for project X. So only I was trying to figure out the slots per query.

Comment: can you confirm that project X is your billing project?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant is there any update on this? Any new feature that will help me get this?

Comment: @rish0097 - not that I am aware of. I will double check and if something found - will answer on your yesterday's question

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I know this is an old question and you probably know already that the Jobs API can now be used for this (my answer about this below).

Comment: @EbenduToit - just noticed this comment - sure of course. we have it nicely built into our Potens.io tools via visualization on query and workflows level

Answer (score 1):

You can get per-query slot utilisation using the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables for jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#schema).

Example query to get the slot utilisation of today's queries of the current project:

```sql
SELECT
  project_id,
  job_id,
  start_time,
  end_time,
  query,
  total_slot_ms,
  total_bytes_processed/1e9 AS gbs_processed,
  destination_table.table_id AS destination_table
FROM
`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE DATE(creation_time)=CURRENT_DATE
```

The `total_slot_ms` field is what you're looking for, I guess.

In Google's words, it expresses the "Slot-milliseconds for the job over its entire duration." (from the [schema documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#schema)).

There are equivalent `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables for individual users (`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER`) and for the whole organisation (`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION`).

Comment: I don't think total_slot_ms is the same as the number of slots used which is what the OP was asking about.

Comment: Yeah, the number of slots used is a quantity that changes from time to time. To get the _average_ slot used during the query, one can sum `total_slot_ms` and divide by the query duration in milliseconds.