# Check number of slots used by a query in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way to check how many slots were used by a query over the period of its execution in BigQuery? I checked the execution plan but I could just see the Slot Time in ms but could not see any parameter or any graph to show the number of slots used over the period of execution. I even tried looking at Stackdriver Monitoring but I could not find anything like this. Please let me know if it can be calculated in some way or if I can see it somewhere I might've missed seeing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know the number of slots used by Bigquery query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40750393/how-do-i-know-the-number-of-slots-used-by-bigquery-query)

Comment: Okay. Is there no update on it since 2016?

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery now provides a key in the Jobs API JSON called "timeline".  This structure provides "statistics.query.timeline[].completedUnits" which you can obtain either during job execution or after. If you choose to pull this information after a job has executed, "completedUnits" will be the cumulative sum of all the units of work (slots) utilised during the query execution.

The question might have two parts though:  (1) Total number of slots utilised (units of work completed) or (2) Maximum parallel number of units used at a point in time by the query.

For (1), the answer is as above, given by "completedUnits".
For (2), you might need to consider the maximum value of queryPlan.parallelInputs across all query stages, which would indicate the maximum "number of parallelizable units of work for the stage" (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation)

If, after this, you additionally want to know if the 2000 parallel slots that you are allocated across your entire on-demand query project is sufficient, you'd need to find the point in time across all queries taking place in your project where the slots being utilised is at a maximum.  This is not a trivial task, but Stackdriver monitoring provides the clearest view for you on this.

Comment: Timeline gives you the totalSlotsMs in a specific point in time defined by elapsedMs.

Answer (score 0):

A BigQuery job will report the total number of slot-milliseconds from the extended query stats in the job metadata, which is analogous to computational cost.  Each stage of the query plan also indicates input stats for the stage, which can be used to indicate the number of units of work each stage dispatched.

More details about the representation can be found in the [REST reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs) for jobs.  See `query.statistics.totalSlotMs` and `statistics.query.queryPlan[].parallelInputs` for more information.

Comment: Sorry this is not very clear, Can you provide a more detail example of what you mean

Comment: What do you exactly don't understand, Tamir? Maybe I can help you. Anyway, there's more info too here in the documentation about [Query Plan Explanation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation#api_sample_representation).